# When editing my own profile visible under my contact dashboard, it does not enter CiviCRM "civicrm_post"API hook?

Tags: wordpress, contact-view

When I try to edit my profile fields from my own contact dashboard as seen in the two images attached and click save, It does not seem to invoke civicrm_post hook in WordPress instance.
[image]

```
add_filter( 'civicrm_post', 'alter_profiles_event', 10, 4  );

function alter_profiles_event($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef){
   if ($objectName == 'Profile'){
    print_r($op);
    print_r($objectRef);
    die('ed');
    //does not enter here.
   }
}
```

How can I make sure the hook is invoked?

Comment: I'd be surprised if `civicrm_post` didn't fire at all. Have you traced without testing for `$objectName`?

Answer (score 0):

Add following line before `add_filter` function:

`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');`